# ¿Existe algún tipo equivalente a (void*) en C#? (en entorno seguro) punteros a instancias de clases para hacer un "semáforo"

Tags: c#, punteros, semaphore, instancias

Necesito hacer una especie de semáforo. Lo quiero para controlar "instancias de clases" en vez de hilos de procesos como sería lo habitual. El caso es que necesito poder pasar el puntero "this" como parametro a una función. Si estuviera en C++ usaría (void*) y luego haría un cast y todo solucionado. Pero en C# el compilador me dice que solo puedo usar eso en entornos no seguros. Supongo que existe algun "tipo" que me permita hacer eso pero no he logrado encontrarlo aún.

Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:

```
///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class InstanceSemaphore
{
    public static void *current;
    public void* selft;   
    ///-------------------------------------------------- 
    //guardar la instancia de quien lo invoca
    public InstanceSemaphore(void* selft)
    {
        this.selft = selft;
    }
    ///-------------------------------------------------- 
    //guardar la instancia si no está siendo usado por otro
    public bool Set(void* selft)
    {
        if (current != null)
        {
            current = selft;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ///-------------------------------------------------- 
    //solo liberer la instacia si si fue el mismo que la guardó
    public void Free(void* selft)
    {
        if (current == selft) current = null;
    }
    ///-------------------------------------------------- 
    //comprobar si la variable está ocupada
    public bool IsBusy()
    {
       return current != null;
    }
}
///-------------------------------------------------- 
///-------------------------------------------------- 
///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class MyClass
{
    InstanceSemaphore semaphore;
    public MyClass()
    {
        semaphore = new InstanceSemaphore((MyClass*)this);
    }
    public void Method() //
    {
        if (semaphore.IsBusy()) return;
        
        semaphore.Set((MyClass*)this);

        //solo yo puedo hacer cosas en este momento
        //que todos los demás esperen a que yo termine

        semaphore.Free((MyClass*)this);
    }
}
```

///--------------------------------------------------

No he podido probar el código asi que es posible que haya algún error. Pero yo creo que mas o menos puede servir para que se entienda la idea que tengo en mente.

¿Existe algún tipo de dato, método o algo que me permita hacer esto?
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Me parece que tratas de reinventar la rueda :) Viniendo de C++ entiendo lo que intentas, pero en C# la forma de funcionar es diferente, los punteros no se usan. Puedes explicar un poco para que quieres el semaforo a ver si te puedo dirigir a la mejor manera de hacerlo en C#?

Comment: Como información, `System.Threading` tiene una clase [`Semaphore`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0). Pero dado que en C# usar hilos en crudo ya no se debería utlizar (existe [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-5.0) para ello), por eso pregunto que es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Es para un juego... tengo un personaje y hace un montón de cosas (corre, salta obtaculos, salta plataformas.... ) Todas las funciones están dentro de un loop infito y aprovechan ese loop para hacer las iteraciones... quiero impedir que dos funciones diferentes hagan cosas simultaneamente... estoy usando saltos condicionales para impedirlo pero es un lio terrible porque se usan un montón de variables... sin embargo si uso un semaforo solamente usaré un variable "global" y común para todas las funciones y estaré 100% de que el resto de funciones estarán bloqueadas

Comment: Si, pero System.Threading no me sirve... no son procesos concurrentes... si uso ese semaforo bloquearé el único hilo que hay en ejecución XD.... tiene que ser un bloqueador de Instancias o  métodos... voy a darle un vistazo a eso de Task que no tengo ni idea de los que és... Muchas gracias Pikoh!!

Comment: Si tu programación esta dentro de un lazo infinito, entiendo que es lineal (se comprueba una tecla por ejemplo, y con un if se ejecuta un método mas o menos). Por que ibas a tener una condición en la que se ejecutaran dos metodos al mismo tiempo? Edito: ademas dices que no son concurrentes, por lo que no puede darse el caso que se ejecuten dos al mismo tiempo

Comment: Si si... eso con el Player no hay ningún problema.... el problema es con el enemigo... es una pequeña inteligencia artificilal... para que entiendas comofunciona... literalmente es como un ciego que va dando golpes a las cosas que tiene alrededor con su bastón (RayCast) y asi mas o menos sabe lo que tiene que ir haciendo (Es una loura) XD

Comment: Aha si, se lo que es raycasting. Pero sigo sin entender. El enemigo supongo que lo mueves tambien dentro del bucle principal de juego, antes o despues de comprobar ls movimientos del jugador. Y eso tambien es lineal. Resumiendo, no entiendo que pueda habe interferencias si no hay tareas concurrentes :)

Comment: Noes  exactamente al mismo tiempo.... pero para que lo entiendas... a lo mejor una funcion necesita 10 o 20 frames para ejecutarse completamente y otra tambien... a lo mejor en frame 10 una se a jecutado la mitad y la otra una cuarta parte.... parece raro pero es asi

Comment: Vale, con lo cual si que es concurrente de cierta manera. Cuando mueves al enemigo, no haces todo el movimiento completo de una vez, sino que vas moviendolo a un frame por iteracion del bucle...es algo asi?

Comment: SI, exacto!! Es lo que tiene aprovechar el loop infinito para hacer las iteraciones.... pero asi se ejecuta mas rápido... si llenas el código con blucles a la larga se empezaría a relentizar demasiado

Comment: Estamos ensuciando la pregunta con los comentarios. Creo que lo mejor es que cuando quieras te pases por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), y asi seguro que nos entedemos mejor :)

Comment: Fui al chat pero no estabas ahi... A donde fué toda nustra conversación? La borraste? Yo espero que los demas puedan verla... seguro que hay mas de uno que me hace las mismas preguntas que tu....

Comment: Me refería al [chat general](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), donde mas gente puede ayudar. Y no, de momento no he eliminado ningun comentario

Comment: Ahh, ok!! Si la conversación ha vuelto a aparecer.... se me acaba de ocurrir una idea!! voy a usar el Tipo "string" y en vez de psar el puntero this a secas voy a pasr esto "this.ToString()" creo que podría funcionar :-) voy a hacer la prueba!!

Comment: Al final después de 2 horas peleandome con ello lo conseguí... \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al problema es la siguiente:

```
///--------------------------------------------------
using System;
///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class ObjectReferenceSemaphore
{   
    public static System.Object current;
    public System.Object selft;    

    //guardar la referencia de quien lo invoca
    public ObjectReferenceSemaphore(System.Object selft)
    {
        this.selft = selft;
    }
    //guardar la referencia si no está siendo usado por otro
    public bool Set(System.Object selft)
    {
        if (current == null)
        {
            current = selft;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //solo liberer la referencia si fue el mismo que la guardó
    public void Free(System.Object selft)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(current, selft)) current = null;
    }
    //comprobar si la variable está ocupada
    public bool IsBusy()
    {
        return current != null && !object.ReferenceEquals(current, selft);
    }
 
}
///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class MyClass
{
    ObjectReferenceSemaphore semaphore;

    public MyClass()
    {
        semaphore = new ObjectReferenceSemaphore(this);
    }
    public void Method(System.Object other, int i, int x, int y) 
    {
        //bloquear a si mismo si hay otra instancia en ejecución
        if (semaphore.IsBusy()) return;

        if (i >= x && i <= y)
        {
            //bloquear otras instancias y permitir la ejecución propia
            semaphore.Set(this);

        } else semaphore.Free(this);//desbloquear a las demás


        Console.Write("\n[" + i + "] " + ObjectReferenceSemaphore.current + " \t" + 
                        semaphore.selft.GetHashCode() + " \t" + other.GetHashCode());
    }
}

///-------------------------------------------------- 
public class InfiniteLoop
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        MyClass b = new MyClass();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            a.Method(b,i, 0,10);
            b.Method(a,i, 10,20);
        }
    }
}
///-------------------------------------------------- 
//C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe test.cs
///-------------------------------------------------- 
///Salida de la consola
///--------------------------------------------------

[0] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[1] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[2] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[3] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[4] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[5] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[6] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[7] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[8] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[9] MyClass     46104728        12289376
[10] MyClass    46104728        12289376
[11]            46104728        12289376
[11] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[12] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[13] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[14] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[15] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[16] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[17] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[18] MyClass    12289376        46104728
[19] MyClass    12289376        46104728

///--------------------------------------------------
Si alguien me da una solución mas simple y eficiente le daré la respuesta por valida.
Muchas gracias!!
```