# ¿Cómo iterar o recorer una jerarquia de datos de objetos? C#

Tags: c#, objeto, iteradores

Me gustaría obtener una lista de objetos a partir de la última instancia de la jerarquía.

Lo estoy intentado hacer como muestra el siguente código pero evidentemente no funciona:

```
//------------------------------
public class C
{
    B b;
    List<System.Object> l;

    public C()
    {
      l = new List<System.Object>();

      System.Object MyObject = (System.Object)b;
     
      MyObject--;
      l.Add(MyObject);
      Console.Write("\n " + MyObject +" "+ MyObject.GetHashCode());

      MyObject--;
      l.Add(MyObject);
      Console.Write("\n " + MyObject +" "+ MyObject.GetHashCode());
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class B
{
    C c;
    public B()
    {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class A
{
    B b;
    public A()
    {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
//------------------------------
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       A a = new A();
    }
}
//------------------------------

Y me gustaría obtener una salida como esta (Nombre de la clase y HashCode)
//------------------------------
//Salida
0 B 46104728
1 A 12289376
```

¿cómo iterar o recorer una jerarquia como esa?
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: A ver creo que no estas claro en lo que dices, para hablar de jerarquia en clases, debe existir herencia entre ellas y tu en lo que pones no tienes ninguna relacion de herencia entre clases, no logro entender lo que quieres, estas confundido en los terminos que empleas, por favor revisa tu pregunta y da mas detalles. Otra cosa puede ser que te refieras a estructura de datos jerarquicas, como puede ser los arboles, el cual esta compuesto por nodos lo s cuales si tienen una relacion de jerarquia entre ellos. Aclara a que te refieres

Comment: Hola!! Si, es posible que sea eso. A veces confundo conceptos muy básicos, Es lo que tiene ser autodidacta... Cuando me ocurre esto me siento como un analfabeto :-( .... porfavor mira esto y sabrás exactamente a lo que me estoy refiriendo. Muchas gracias!! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422836/alg%c3%ban-m%c3%a9todo-para-saber-el-nombre-o-jerarqu%c3%ada-de-la-s-clase-s-que-encapsulan/422876#422876

Comment: Por que mejor no dices lo que pide tu ejercicio pa entenderte mejor

Comment: Lo que quiero es saber cual es el objeto que está en el mas alto nivel de la jerarquia en "la estrutura de datos". Verás, hice una especie de semaforo... "pero no es en programación concurrente". y me interasa saber cual es el objeto que lo invoca para poder usarlo en multiples objetos y no solo en uno. Aqui está el código del semaforo por si te interesa velo... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421791/existe-alg%c3%ban-tipo-equivalente-a-void-en-c-en-entorno-seguro-punteros-a-i  Conseguí lo que buscaba en el enlace que te pasé por primera vez... pero el código tiene ciertos inconvenietes

Comment: poder iterar esos arboles de nodos simplificaria mucho las cosas

Comment: Ok, he hecho unos cuantos cambios en la pregunta... espero que asi se entienda mejor lo que quiero hacer... Aunque sinceramente aún no tengo muy claro si a eso se le puede llamar árbol según lo que acabo de estar leyendo creo que no es el caso... simplemente son x clases con x miembros totalmente aleatorios...